# Load script and execute when link is triggered

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a cookie banner loading on all pages and I want to prevent the script from loading on the Privacy Policy page. But the script is needed to access the cookies settings.
Main scripts that needed to load the cookie banner

```
<script src="lib/js/cookieconsent.js"></script>
```

and this script initiate the cookie banner.

```
<script>
    function f1() {
        let loadCookie2 = document.createElement("script");
        loadCookie2.type = "text/javascript";
        loadCookie2.setAttribute("src", "lib/js/cookieconsent-init.js");
        document.body.appendChild(loadCookie2);
    }
</script>
```

the link that triggers the settings

`<a href="javascript:f1();" type="button" data-cc="c-settings">cookie settings</a>`

`data-cc="c-settings"` loads the cookie settings, and when I click on the link it first loads the script and after a second click it shows the settings.

How to prevent that can I trigger them simultaneously?

Comment: Post any working fiddle. Would help to understand better.

Comment: _"`data-cc="c-settings"` loads the cookie settings"_ - we'd need more details about how that is actually implemented ... Presumably your cookie script binds an event handler to elements with that attribute, so that handler won't be set, before the script has not loaded and initialized. But it might provide additional methods to call the settings dialog directly, or maybe also options to load the script without directly triggering the banner. You should start by consulting its documentation on that.

Comment: @CBroe the implementation is here https://github.com/orestbida/cookieconsent/blob/master/src/cookieconsent.js

Comment: @kevin I want to add that but I thought the question was simple and it is based on this cookies https://github.com/orestbida/cookieconsent

Comment: If you set `autorun` to false in your config options, it will not automatically show the cookie banner. You can call the `show` method then to trigger it.

Comment: @CBroe thank you, this is really good what about the other pages (home, products ,....etc) that I want to use autorun without trigger.

Comment: Embed a _different_ init script on those then ...?

Comment: Or use one script, but set the `autorun` option dynamically, based on what page you are currently on (check via `location.href` or similar.)

Comment: @CBroe both are great ideas thank you I will try that

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @CBroe comment this is the solution
In the configuration file. cookieconsent-init.js

uncomment `autorun` and add

```
autorun = window.location !== "privacy" //this should be the privacy url
```